# Jquery - Show progress cursor when browser is busy/loading (windows like)

Tags: jquery

I want to show the cursor as `progress` on every load.

Is it possible to show the cursor as `progress` when the browser is busy?

If not, is it possible to show the cursor as `progress` if jQuery is posting 
without adding code to every jQuery post function?

I'm looking for a clean and global solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
$().ajaxStart(function(){
   $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$().ajaxStop(function(){
   $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

and it will invoked when an ajax process called...

Comment: The `cursor` value you're looking for is `wait` or `progress`, not `busy`. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

Comment: @Peter: are u executing an ajax request??
because it will invoked when an ajax process called...

Comment: this doesn't work for me on IE9.  I found another article that suggests doing `$('*').css('cursor', 'wait')` which works great but has the disadvantage that it wipes out any cursors attached to items on the page.  any recommendations?

Comment: @Peter try $(document).ajaxStart(function(){...}

Comment: Thanks - worked perfectly with the (document) fix for IE9. I'm glad I delved into the comments, so worth updating the original answer if possible.